# How to disable rendering in QML WebView?

Tags: qt, webview, qml, qtquick2, qtwebkit

I am currently building an application that makes use of QML `WebView` (`import QtWebKit 3.0`). The users need to resize the `WebView` very often (I am using a QML `SplitView`), however this leads to the UI to lag extremely whenever the app window is resized. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: You'd probably need to profile it and see where the time is spent.

Comment: @KubaOber I did that and the drop in frame rate, happens exactly when I resize the SplitView (changing the width of the WebView) when its updateLayout() and moveHandle() functions are triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the `width` and `height` properties change `scale` property of the `WebView`.

- At beginning of the resize save initial values of `width` and `height`.
- On resize don't change `width` and `height`. Instead set `scale` to newWidth divided by width at beginning of the resize.
- When resize ends set new values of `width` and `height` to these properties and set `scale` to 1.

EDIT:
Since you don't have control of `width` and `height` properties you can replace `WebView` with `Rectangle` with color set to `"transparent"`. Then you can place `WebView` on `Rectangle` and watch how `width` and `height` of `Rectangle` are changing.

Now two things.

If you don't know when resize starts and when ends use `Timer` with interval for example 100ms. Restart `Timer` and update `scale` every time `width` and `height` of `Rectangle` changes. When `Timer` is triggered set real `width` and `height`.

If ratio of `width` and `height` of Rectangle is not constant use QML object `Scale`. With it you can change `xScale` and `yScale` independently.

Comment: That is a good idea. However since I said I am using a SplitView, I don't have control over the height and width property.

Comment: @daljit97 I think that changing `scale` or using `Scale` object is all you need. For more information see my edited answer. If you are still not satisfied please provide simple example of code you want to work without lag.

Comment: I followed your approach and it works, however the WebView becomes invisible when scaling. It is much better then before though, thank you.

Comment: @daljit97 Strange. It can look stretched unnaturally but it shouldn't be invisible.

Comment: @daljit97 You certainly have full control of the properties, you just need to interpose some of your own code between the container and the view.