# Qt/QML: WebView resizes really slowly when window resizing

Tags: qt, webview, resize, qml

I have a Qt application with QML and I need to display a webBrowser inside a QML file.

I have tried with Qml (using 'WebEngineView - QtWebEngine 1.1' or 'WebView - QtWebView 1.0') and in Qt (using 'QWebEngineView - Qt 5.6', with or without 'QWebEnginePage')

The HTML is loaded properly, but when I resize the window, the content (including the scroll bar) is resized slowly to the new window size, so it has a really bad effect.

My code is like that:

1. QML:

   Item {
       id: rectChatView

   ```
   anchors.fill: parent

   ...

   WebEngineView  // or WebView
   {
       id: chatView
       anchors.fill: parent
       url: "file:///d:\\test.html"
   }

   ...
   ```

   }
2. Qt

With QWebEngineView:

```
QWebEngineView* pViewWeb = new QWebEngineView();
pViewWeb->setWindowTitle("QWebEngineView");
pViewWeb->load(QUrl("file:///d:\\test.html"));
pViewWeb->setMinimumSize(300,300);
pViewWeb->show();
```

or with QWebEnginePage:

```
QWebEnginePage* pPage = new QWebEnginePage();
pPage->load(QUrl("file:///d:\\test.html"));

QWebEngineView* pView = new QWebEngineView();
pView->setWindowTitle("QWebEngineView");
pView->setMinimumSize(300,300);
pView->setPage(pPage);
pView->show();
```

But the 3 ways have the same result, too slow when resizing the window...

Ideas on why the nested browser window is slow to resize?

Comment: The suspicion is that debug mode is interfering. Try to compile and run release.

Comment: I think that I have been solving similar case before. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896264/how-to-disable-rendering-in-qml-webview/31897152#31897152). Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I would be very interested in a solution.